# React not updating the DOM (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs

I have set up a basic react app with hash navigation. Problem is when I click on any link to navigate between pages, I see that the hash in the url is changing properly, as well as I added a `console.log` in my layour's `render` to see if it's getting called and it is, with proper `this.props.children` values, however the page is not rendering anything. If I go to any route and refresh the page I see the correct components rendered, but if I navigate somewhere from there noting gets rendered until I refresh again.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { IndexRoute, Router, Route, Link, hashHistory as history } from 'react-router';

class Layout extends React.Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props, document.location.hash);

    return <div>
      <div>
        <span>LEYAUTI MLEAYTI {Math.random()}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
      <div>
        {this.props.params.project}
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}

class CreateProject extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Create PROEKT</h1>
    </div>
  }
}

class Projects extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>PROEKTI MROEKTI</h1>
      <Link to="/projects/create">New project</Link>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Projects}/>
        <Route path="projects/create" component={CreateProject}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app-root'));
```

Here is a visual of what's happening in the console when I navigate on a couple routes, but the DOM remains unchanged

[image]

Comment: You might need to add a forward slash (`/`) at the front of your paths, eg `<Route path="/projects/create"`

Comment: @Aron well the routing appears to be working, however I tried your suggestion but it didn't have much of an effect. Problem is with the rendering part, because my components are getting passed correctly.

Comment: So the problem is that although the route changes and the render function runs (cos you can see the console.log), nothing changes on the page until  you refresh?

Comment: @Aron yep, I see the initial page that was loaded on whatever route was opened the first time.

Comment: I see. Hm. Can you post an example of one of your components that has a `Link` in it?

Comment: It's difficult to see from here why it's not working. I'd recommend creating a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) that showcases the problem so we can try and debug it that way.

Comment: @Aron well I'm using webpack, how can I put this code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @php_nub_qq a code snippet on here would be more useful. If you remove your `imports` and add `<script>` tags linking to the relevant libraries, it should be possible. You can put the routing code and the component definitions all together, rather than in separate files.

Comment: @TomFenech I fixed it, hope it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I got down to the bottom of it.

The problem was that I was including my `client.min.js` file *before* the default `app.js` file of laravel 5.4's default layout. For some reason it broke react in a very weird way. What I had to do is switch the order in which the two files were included.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with hashHistory. Which react-router version are you using? With v4 and above, you need to use history like so -

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
const history = createHistory()
// pass history to the Router....
```

Comment: I'm using version 3 of react router and history. This is not a problem with the routing, it is not updating the DOM at all even when I do `this.setState` no changes are being applied to the DOM

Comment: I can't share the repo because it's a private company one. I just tried to create a new public repo containing just this code and then it worked. So the problem is somewhere in my current project, now I'm including this in a laravel project, I don't know if that has any significance but I really don't know what to think at this point..

Comment: I'd be really superstitious and check the repo setup, try cloning and npm install in a different folder etc.

Comment: Well I think I found the problem... Currently my code is being rendered using `blade`, where the `srcipt` tag for `client.min.js` is in a `@section`. If I remove all blade markup from the view and leave just the html tags then react works just fine. Do you have any ideas what might be the deal with that?

Comment: Sorry, never used it.

Comment: Well turned out to be something rather unexpected, thank you for your time sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your component didn't actually unmount/remount if you only update your hashtag in your url. The route however, is updated. So you can only see the component loads content for once when you refresh the page.

You will need to create state variables and update it in a routeChange handler callback and bind the updated state variable to your view by using setState. Then the component can get updated.

See this post for how to add the route change listener (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554)